# How to call a generic method directly?

Tags: java, generics

Here is the method I am calling:

```
public static <T extends Something> Group<T> getGroup() { ... }
```

If I wanted to store the result in a variable, I would do something like this:

```
Group<SomethingSubClass> group = StaticClass.getGroup();
```

How would I call the method without storing it in a variable?

```
StaticClass.getGroup();
```

The above is what I tried, but I am unsure (mostly don't think it is possible from the way my method is) to add the generic type T.

Solution:

```
StaticClass.<SomethingSubClass>getGroup();
```

Comment: `StaticClass.<SomethingSubClass>getGroup()`

Comment: Because it side-effects?

Comment: @ChrisMartin The method, internally, cannot use the type `T` for anything useful.

Comment: @chrylis So I don't have to create a variable for it and use it directly within another method.

Comment: @dalawh You don't have to create a variable for it at all. Just ignore the return value.

Comment: It's amazing how material on generics never seems to cover this, even though it would seem to be an important topic.

Comment: @Mer Yeah. This was new to me. I am glad that I found this out.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need anything special. Just invoke it as

```
StaticClass.getGroup();
```

You will simply be ignore the return value. The type argument will be inferred as `Something`, which is what you'd have access to in your method anyway.

You would specify an actual type argument by doing

```
StaticClass.<SomeTypeThatExtendsSomething>getGroup();
```

but you don't need that since the only part of your method that makes use of the generic type is the return type, which you are discarding.